# Changing MySQL login credentials with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I've seen a bunch of links about changing the credentials that hibernate uses to connect to a database, but nothing about whether or not you can use hibernate to execute something like `SET PASSWORD FOR 'username'= PASSWORD('password')`. I'd also like to be able to grand users privileges, display all the databases and create new users as well. Basically can I do anything other than table operations with Hibernate?

For example I've tried the following to create a user:

```
SessionFactory factory = new  Configuration.configuration().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try{
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    String query = "CREATE USER 'testUser' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'";
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(query);
    tx.commit();
}catch(HibernateException e){
    if(tx != null){
        tx.rollback();
    }
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    session.close();
}
factory.close();
```

I know it runs everything correctly, but no user is created.

Comment: Have you tried to? What happened?

Comment: I haven't. I can get to the point where I can formulate a SQLQuery, but I don't know where to go from there. I can't find what method to use on it to do what I want, and I don't know if SQLQuery is the right class to use for some of the operations I want.

Comment: Post what you've tried, if you want to get any assistance. Also suggest tagging with java so the java folks notice it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `executeUpdate()` on your `SQLQuery` instance - `query.executeUpdate()` - this will issue your `CREATE USER` statement to the database. Currently you're creating the query instance and doing nothing with it.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought to try that, it seemed like executeUpdate() was reserved for CRUD ops.